# execute php script with argument in phing

Tags: php, phing

First, let's say that I have a php script , I use this script in command line , and I call this one with some arguments.

In my script I use

```
if(isset($argv)&&(isset($argv[1]))) 
{
}
```

but is not that the problem , I can use the php script in `cmd` (I use Windows)

I want to use the same command in my build.xml with phing 
example of the command

```
php /path/indexCLI.php  arg1=arg1value arg2=arg2Value ...
```

How can i have the same behavior using phing

I want to get something like this:

```
<target name="lala" >
    <exec command="php path\indexbin.php  arg1=arg1value arg2=arg2Value" escape="false" />
</target>
```

Or something better if that is available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have this. It already works the way you described it in the code example.